When to put 의 to 로?
To give two examples:
이 경우 역시 기초지방자치단체로서의 권한이 없어
가령 미래로의 여행
Could someone explain please, when to use the two particles 로 and 의 together?

로 alone can't modify 명사.
로의 modifies 명사.
because 의 makes the word-phrase adjective.

So in cases like "This is the road to Disneyland", I would combine the particles?

'이것은 디즈니랜드로의 길이다' sounds like a translated sentence. '이것은 디즈니랜드로 가는 길이다' might sound more natural. —or even more naturally, '이 길은 디즈니랜드로 향한다.' or '이 길은 디즈니랜드로 통한다'

You add 의 after 로 (and other similar auxiliary particles) to create a proper noun phrase.
미래로 여행 is grammatically unclear because Korean particles like (으)로 basically work with a verb and not directly with a noun.  "a journey to the future" works fine in English but Korean particles cannot work with nouns with the same kind of flexibility. It may sound odd but that's how it is. It could be because the distinction between noun and adjective/verb goes deeper in Korean than in English.  For example, Korean doesn't have words that can function as both such as "witness", "delinquent", "Spanish" and others in English.
So "a journey to the future" should be expressed as 미래로의 여행 with 의. This way it is clearly about 여행 that goes to the future.  But note that it is a relatively formal and literary expression. For example, a colloquial sentence like "How was your trip to New York" would be expressed as 뉴욕 여행은 어땠어요? or 뉴욕(에) 오는/갔던 여행은 어땠어요?.  뉴욕으로의 여행은 어땠어요? means the same thing but it sounds a little like from a textbook.
Here are examples contrasting the particles in normal usage and in a noun phrase.

너와 만났다 (I met with you).  너와의 만남 (My encounter with you).
독자로부터 편지가 왔다 (A letter came from a reader). 독자로부터의 편지 (a letter from a reader).
리더로서 자질이 없다 (They lack the qualities as a leader). 리더로서의 자질 (qualities as a leader).

In a sentence, it can often work both with 의 and without 의.  For example, both 리더로서 자질이 없다 and 리더로서의 자질이 없다 have largely the same meaning, except that the former seems to indicate the person is already a leader while the latter does not (but it's not a strong distinction).
Your first example sentence can similarly work both with and without 의.

기초자방단체로서 권한이 없어 = As the lowest local government, (We/They) lack the prerogatives.
기초지방단체로서의 권한이 없어 = We lack the prerogatives of a lowest local government.

Again both are fine sentences with different grammar.  There is only a subtle difference in meaning which may or may not be important depending on the situation.
